# optimizing a complex query in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have two questions here but i am asking them at once as i think they are inter-related.

I am working with a complex query (Multiple joins + sub queries) and the table is pretty huge as well (around 2,00,000 records in this table).

A part of this query (a LEFT JOIN) is required to find a record which has a second lowest value in a cetain column among all the records associated with the primary key of the first table. For now I have isolated this part and thinking on the lines of -

```
SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY `myvalue` ASC LIMIT 1,1;
```

But there is a case where, if there is only 1 record in the table, it must return that record instead of NULL. So my first question is how do write a query for this ?

Secondly, considering the size of the table and the time its already taking to run even after creating indexes, I understand that adding any more complexity to it in order to achieve the above part might affect the querying time dramatically.

I cannot decompose joins because I need to get some of the columns for the ORDER BY clause (the application has an option to sort the result by these columns, the above column "myvalue" being one of them)

What would be the way(s) to approach this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work

```
COALESCE(
  (SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY `myvalue` ASC LIMIT 1,1), 
  (SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY `myvalue` ASC LIMIT 0,1))
```

It selects the first non null value from the list provided.

As for the complexity of the query, post the whole thing so we can take a look at it.

Comment: that worked. thanks a ton. I also managed to improve the query performance to some extent after adding this. So its all good for now.